# Pass an array list as an argument to pthread_create

Tags: c++, multithreading, arraylist

I am attempting to pass an Array List as below as an argument to a class member thread function which in turn calls another member function but i am failing to retrieve the values inside the thread function.

Code :-

```
 pthread_t t2;
 int Coordinates[] = {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)};
 pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &Class::thread_func,(void*) Coordinates);


void* Class::thread_func(void *arg)
{
  int *coord = (int *) arg;
  for(int i=0; i< sizeof(coord); i++)
  {
  classObj->doSomething(coord[i][0], coord[i][1]);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong, been struggling with this for a while and I am not too experienced with Multithreading.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int Coordinates[]` only has one dimension. Your initializer also (`(42,1)` is evaluated to 1, that `,` is in fact a coma operator). Why not use vectors of points, and `std::thread`?

Comment: `int Coordinates[]` Did you have working code *without the thread*? Also C++ now has it's own `std::thread` and some associated utilities (e.g. `std::async`), these can handle passing C++ types for you, any reason for not using them?

Comment: You can't use sizeof(coord) to get number of elements inside thread_func, because it is just a regular int pointer now, not an array.

Comment: I can't use **std:thread** because i'm writing testing code to test legacy functions written with pthread.

Comment: Please fix the code, Coordinates declaration doesn't work and gives warnings. Also it does NOT create twodimensional array as you expect. So it doesn't work even before you start multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Coordinates` is passed `void *` so there is ONLY one address stored. No size of initial array. You MUST pass size extra, by passing custom struct, `std::pair` or `std::vector` or append something that is invalid coordinate and stop on that.

If you can use `std::vector` and so on you can do it like this (just pass vector by pointer):

```cpp
void* thread_func(std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> *coord) {
  for(int i=0; i < coord->size(); i++)
  {
    cout << (*coord)[i][0] << " " << (*coord)[i][1]<<endl;;
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(){
  pthread_t t2;
  std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> Coordinates= {{0,10}, {1,11}, {2,22}};
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, (void * (*)(void *))thread_func, &Coordinates);
  pthread_join(t2, NULL);
}
```